# How to use UGUI mask and custom font correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to use mask component to show apart of a text with custom font.

But like the pictures say:

When I use custom font with "None (Material)", the mask works very well, but the text is abnormal. (Picture 1)

Someone taught me to change the text's material to "Sprites-Default", then the text will show correctly. And when I change the material, the text show normal indeed, but the mask doesn't work, it can't cover the text which is out of the mask. (Picture 2)

How should I do to make all of them work well?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use Sprites-Default material, the unity warned me "Material Sprite/Default doesn't have stencil properties". So I copy stencil properties from UI-defaultFont.shader. Thanks god it works.

Here is my modified shader:

Create a material with this shader and use this material.[image]

```
Shader "Custom/SpritesDefaultFont"
{
Properties
{
    [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0

    _StencilComp ("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
    _Stencil ("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
    _StencilOp ("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
    _StencilWriteMask ("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
    _StencilReadMask ("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255
}

SubShader
{
    Tags
    { 
        "Queue"="Transparent" 
        "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
        "RenderType"="Transparent" 
        "PreviewType"="Plane"
        "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
    }

    Stencil
    {
        Ref [_Stencil]
        Comp [_StencilComp]
        Pass [_StencilOp] 
        ReadMask [_StencilReadMask]
        WriteMask [_StencilWriteMask]
    }

    Cull Off
    Lighting Off
    ZWrite Off
    Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

    Pass
    {
    CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma multi_compile _ PIXELSNAP_ON
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata_t
        {
            float4 vertex   : POSITION;
            float4 color    : COLOR;
            float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
            fixed4 color    : COLOR;
            half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        fixed4 _Color;

        v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
        {
            v2f OUT;
            OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
            OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
            OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
            #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
            OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap (OUT.vertex);
            #endif

            return OUT;
        }

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
            c.rgb *= c.a;
            return c;
        }
    ENDCG
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However when I tried it I found your shader is missing the property _ColorMask. Adding `_ColorMask ("Color Mask", Float) = 15` at the end of Properties and `ColorMask [_ColorMask]` after lighting/ztest/cull/blend resulted in a shader that is maskable and works for font materials.